# How to Perform LDAP authentication in Perl

Tags: perl, authentication, ldap, perl-module, openldap

I want to write **LDAP authentication** code for my **Perl** script.Below I have provided the sample USER details and AD server details.
I am not able to authenticate the LDAP user with the variable provided below. 
I am using `Net::LDAP` library but I am still not able to achieve my objective.
I need help to understand LDAP authentication process and the logic I need to imply to authenticate an LDAP user.

One doubt I have is "do i need to verify whether the LDAP user exist or not in the AD server or not?"

```
USER:cn=Feroz,dc=Alam,dc=com 
PWD:nike 
HOST:10.10.10.10 
PORT:1234
AD_USER:CN=Feroz,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,DC=Alam,DC=com
AD_PWD:addidas
AD_SERVER:myadserver.com
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new($HOST, port=>$PORT) or die "Cant Connect to LDAP server:$@";
#IF I REMOVE THE PORT NO i AM GETTING THE ERROR "Cant Connect to LDAP server:IO::Socket::INET: connect:"
if ( $ldap->bind($USER,password=>$PWD) ) {
    print "Successful Authentication\n";
    #IT IS GIVING ME SUCCESSFUL AUTHENTICATION MESSAGE EVEN IF ENTER THE WRONG PASSWORD
}
else{
    print "Unsuccessful Authentication\n";
    push(@downlist, $server);
    --$upcount;
}
$ldap->unbind();

DEBUG LOGS:
Net::LDAP=HASH(0x488268) sending:
Net::LDAP=HASH(0x488268) received:
0000   12: SEQUENCE {
0002    1:   INTEGER = 1
0005    7:   [APPLICATION 1] {
0007    1:     ENUM = 49
000A    0:     STRING = ''
000C    0:     STRING = ''
000E     :   }
000E     : }
Successful Authentication
Net::LDAP=HASH(0x488268) sending:
```

Please help......

Comment: Please also show how you have used Net::LDAP and explain what's happening when you try to authenticate. Something must be going on. It's impossible to debug without seeing what you've done.

Comment: Here is the code that I am using to perform LDAP authentication

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new($HOST, port=>$PORT) or die "Cant Connect to LDAP server:$@";
      
    if ( $ldap->bind($USER,password=>$PWD) ) {
        # successfull authentication
  print "Successful Authentication\n";
    }
 else{
  print "Unsuccessful Authentication\n";
  push(@downlist, $server);
  --$upcount;
 }
  $ldap->unbind();

Comment: Please [edit] your question. This is not a forum and comments are not meant for code. It's unreadable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Any ways I have edited my question and the code through which I am trying to achieve it

Comment: I have provided the wrong password but it throwing me the message successful authentication. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Net::LDAP` returns a message object when using the bind method except if there is a code error (in that case I don't know, it may return undef or 0 or a croak).
Anyway that means that, whether authentication is successful or not, your condition will always be true.

I think you need to store the result of bind and test its code, like that:

```
my $mesg = $ldap->bind($USER,password=>$PWD);

if ( $mesg and $mesg->code() == 0 ) {
    print "Successful Authentication\n";
}
else{
    print "Unsuccessful Authentication\n";
    print 'Received error '.$mesg->code().': '$mesg->error()."\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this resolved the issue. this is the correct resolution

Comment: Yay! I'm helpful! :-D